# How can i use the variable graphics only once?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this form1 paint event:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawText("List points", Color.Red, Color.Green, e.Graphics, new Point(369, 90), new Point(469, 90), new Point(480, 83),8.25);
            DrawText("List clouds1", Color.Black, Color.Green, e.Graphics, new Point(369, 110), new Point(469, 110), new Point(480, 103),8.25);
        }
```

And the DrawText method:

```
private void DrawText(string text, Color pen_color, Color brushes_color, Graphics graphics, Point point1, Point point2, Point point3,
                              double font_size)
        {
            this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily.Name, (float)font_size);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(brushes_color);
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(pen_color, 10f))
            {
                Point pt1 = point1;
                Point pt2 = point2;
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, point1, point2);
            }

            graphics.DrawString(text,
                    this.Font, brush, point3);
        }
```

When i call this method twice now from the paint event im using e.Graphics twice.
I wonder if i can create somehow a local Graphics variable in the DrawText method and use it ?

I tried to add in the DrawText method this:

```
Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
```

And then i removed the graphics variable and i dont need to call it using e.Graphics.
But now when i see the text it draw the text is looks like its drawing each time twice.
The text is not thin/normal as it was when i used e.Graphics twice on each time i call the method.

Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: The problem i think is that its doing the CreateGraphics twice and i could use this once in the top of the form but i want to it be a local  variable in the method if i will want to use the method in other projects.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you have done it.  Calling e.Graphics twice does not call CreateGraphics twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is quite correct, if you want to reduce code in paint handler you can create a new class for drawing text, like this:

```
class MyTextDrawer 
{
    private readonly Graphics g;

    public MyTextDrawer(Graphics g) 
    {
        this.g = g;
    }

    public void DrawText(string text, Color pen_color, Color brushes_color, Point point1, Point point2, Point point3,
                          double font_size)
    {
        this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily.Name, (float)font_size);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(brushes_color);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(pen_color, 10f))
        {
            Point pt1 = point1;
            Point pt2 = point2;
            g.DrawLine(pen, point1, point2);
        }

        g.DrawString(text,
                this.Font, brush, point3);
    }

}
```

Usage

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var drawer = new MyTextDrawer(e.Graphics);

    drawer.DrawText("List points", Color.Red, Color.Green, new Point(369, 90), new Point(469, 90), new Point(480, 83),8.25);
    drawer.DrawText("List clouds1", Color.Black, Color.Green, new Point(369, 110), new Point(469, 110), new Point(480, 103),8.25);
}
```

You can also incapsulate pen, font size and others in your class.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is anything wrong with calling the e.graphics twice.  e.Graphics is a local variable, there is no overhead involved with calling it twice, you are simply passing it to the DrawText Method, who is using it.

but if you wanted to you could do

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics
```

Comment: he already has the proper graphics object which will be disposed properly, creating another one is redundant and can lead to resource issues.

Comment: I agree completely about it being redundant and it could lead to resource issues, that is why I said there is no need to create another, but if he really wanted to he could